# How do I get this character to follow its walking path?

Tags: animation

The character walks in place. There is a path in front of it, but the character does not walk along it. How do I resolve this? I am using version 2.79 currently but will switch as soon as the semester is over. Thanks in advance.

Comment: have you clicked on the Follow Path Animate Path button? Maybe share your file (only armature + curve): https://blend-exchange.giantcowfilms.com/

Comment: Thank you very much, moon boots!

Comment: Ok. I tried what you've suggested. The character still walks in place. Do you have any other suggestions @moonboots ?

Comment: please share your file (only armature + curve), use https://blend-exchange.giantcowfilms.com/

Comment: @moonboots I uploaded the file. Thank you in advance for your help.

Comment: you need to give the link  ;)

Comment: I thought I did when I uploaded the file and copied the link. I must be missing a piece of information. I will try again. Thank you, @moonboots

Comment: This is the URL I entered: https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/178213/how-do-i-get-this-character-to-follow-its-walking-path?noredirect=1#comment299084_178213 at the giantcow website.

Comment: Must be this link: [<img src="https://blend-exchange.giantcowfilms.com/embedImage.png?bid=ze78lr9q" />](https://blend-exchange.giantcowfilms.com/b/ze78lr9q/)

Answer (score 1):

You've confused *Object Constraints* with *Bone Constraints*.

If you want your armature to follow a path you need to give your armature a *Follow Path* constraint. If I check the *Properties* panel > *Object Constraints* tab, I don't see any *Follow Path*. Actually you've assigned a *Follow Path* to one of your bones, *Ankle.L*, you will see it if you switch to *Pose* mode, select this bone and click on the *Bone Constraints* tab.

So delete the bone's *Follow Path* constraint and give a *Follow Path* constraint to your armature. After that press <kbd>Alt</kbd><kbd>G</kbd> to make your armature stick to the beginning of the path.

[image]

Comment: Thank you so very much! I did not spot that at all. I wish I could buy you an adult beverage of your choice. Cheers!

Comment: orange juice then! you're welcome  ;)